# Error en tkinter en programa de calculadora básica

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo mis primeros programas en python, estoy utilizando python3.8.2 y el vscode en Linux. Haciendo el programa de calculadora básica, se me presenta un error al tratar de utilizar el borrado del display, a continuación dejo el fragmento de código y el error, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar o darme otra opción para cambiar la forma de borrado, sin tener que cambiar casi todo el código escrito se lo agradeceré

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Calculadora')

display = tk.Entry(root)
display.grid(row=0, columnspan=10, sticky='w'+'e', padx=5, pady=5)

i = 0

def get_number(n):
  global i
  display.insert(i,n)
  i+=1

def get_operation(operator):
  global i
  operator_length = len(operator)
  display.insert(i, operator)
  i+=operator_length
  
def clear_display():
  display.delete(0, END)


# Teclado numérico
tk.Button(root, text='1', command=lambda:get_number(1)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='2', command=lambda:get_number(2)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='3', command=lambda:get_number(3)).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='4', command=lambda:get_number(4)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='5', command=lambda:get_number(5)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='6', command=lambda:get_number(6)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='7', command=lambda:get_number(7)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='8', command=lambda:get_number(8)).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='9', command=lambda:get_number(9)).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='0', command=lambda:get_number(0)).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w'+'e')

# Teclas especiales
tk.Button(root, text='A/C', command=lambda:clear_display()).grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='+', command=lambda:get_operation('+')).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='-', command=lambda:get_operation('-')).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='*', command=lambda:get_operation('*')).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='/', command=lambda:get_operation('/')).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text=' ', command=lambda:get_operation(' ')).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text=',', command=lambda:get_operation(',')).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='(', command=lambda:get_operation('(')).grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text=')', command=lambda:get_operation(')')).grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='%', command=lambda:get_operation('%')).grid(row=4, column=4, sticky='w'+'e')

tk.Button(root, text='⬅').grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=2, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='Exp', command=lambda:get_operation('**')).grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='^2', command=lambda:get_operation('**2')).grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='w'+'e')
tk.Button(root, text='=').grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='w'+'e')


root.mainloop()
```

y el error que me sale al ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "app.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    tk.Button(root, text='A/C', command=lambda:clear_display()).grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='w'+'e')
  File "app.py", line 24, in clear_display
    display.delete(0, END | END)
NameError: name 'END' is not defined
```

no entiendo porque me considera a END como no definida.
Desde ya gracias!

Comment: Será que no has definido `END`? Usualmente es una variable de tkinter que se usa para acortar (y no poner el string `"END"`). Prueba con `tk.END` en su lugar.

Comment: @dannytalentsi en efecto se solucionó con el tk.END gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes solucionar este error de 2 formas:

- Colocando tk.END

> ```
> def clear_display():
>   display.delete(0,tk.END)
> ```

- Colocando 'end'

> ```
> def clear_display():
>   display.delete(0,'end')
> ```

Personalmente prefiero la 2da opción..

Comment: me solucionó el problema, coloqué el tk.END. Gracias @iflores2000